# Inflating a View Inside a Runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

I am attempting to write code that would allow me to have 1-2 views at the top of a listview that are of a different arrangement than the other views in the listview.  I decided to try the method of using addHeaderView() for the 1-2 views that will differ in display.

I have two xml layout files, one that defines the view format that most of the listview views will fall under (list_image_checkbox_row.xml) and one for the Header Views (catalog_featured_row.xml).  The adapter constructor uses list_image_checkbox_row as its resource in the constructor.

I used a Thread to set the adapter and load the views.  I am able to programmatically create views and use addHeaderView to at them to the listview (using the same image resource), but I get errors when I try to use addHeaderView on a view I have inflated from a layout xml file.

```
          handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.sources_list);
            Activity context = BrowseSourceActivity.this;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.catalog_featured_row, null);
            ImageView feat_view = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            feat_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);

            lv.addHeaderView(feat_view);
            setListAdapter(array);
        }
      });
```

I get a force close error and haven't been able to find anything in logcat (when I was trying to debug yesterday I got a NullPointerException).  If I comment out the lv.addHeaderView(feat_view) line, the application does not force close on me.  Here is the code for featured_catalog_row.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions for how to get the inflater to work?

Comment: The UI toolkit is not thread safe. You should only modify the UI from the UI thread. So you need to post a runnable that runs on the UI thread and sets your adapters, views and inflates things.

Comment: @Joseph, the handler is probably executing that `Runnable` on the UI thread.

Comment: Yup it is, sorry. Aah your issue might be related to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12870. You have to call `addHeaderView` or `addFooterView` at least ONCE before setting the adapter, or you cannot add header or footer views after the adapter is set (you can always remove the extra header/footer after setting the adapter). Also you should be setting `view` as the header/footer view unless `view` and `feat_view` are actually the same view, otherwise you've got a parent view floating around that's not attached to any part of the view hierarchy, but it's child is.

Comment: Nice! You are right that I needed addHeaderView(view) and not addHeaderView(feat_view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should store `lv` in an instance variable instead of looking it up dynamically. Note that both `View` and `Activity` have a method called `findViewById`, and so your results will depend on how your code is organized.